# How to tell colleague to stop talking about xy?

Tags: conversation

I'm on **really** good terms with my colleague, we go for lunch every day, we run our department and we communicate efficiently. However, he keeps telling me about xy all the time and I kind of am starting to get a bit tired of it. It's a really pleasant subject to him and matters a lot to him.

Also I know I'm not good at being sensitive so I don't want to risk coming across as rude when I would ask that perhaps we could talk about something else.

How can I say this politely?

Comment: What is xy? Is that some sort of placeholder for a topic you don't want to name here or is xy the proper name of something?

Comment: I would suggest to let him keep talking about xy from time to time even if it bores you a bit. If he is passionate about this topic, this will ensure that your relationship stays good. If you really want to learn how to change a topic without giving offense, you should post a question on interpersonal.stackexchange.com. Such techniques are not really specific to the workplace.

Comment: @GlenPierce [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) - Basically it's when you get fixed more by a solution than the problem it's attempting to solve.

Comment: It's Bitcoin, obviously.

Comment: @Snow I'm quite sure it's just a placeholder. "XY" is commonly used as placeholder in some languages like german.

Comment: @Chaotic it could be veganism or marathon running or Crossfit

Comment: Every time he brings up XY, you bring up YX, where YX is something he doesn't care at all about that you can talk for hours about. Maybe it's your favorite sports team. Maybe it's your 30th level Paladin in World of Warcraft. Maybe it's your comic book collection. If he asks, or doesn't get the hint, just tell him that XY makes him think of YX for some made up reason. "Speaking of XY, have I told you this new thing about YX? ..."

Comment: This might sound like a dumb question, but do you (and/or does he) have anything more interesting to talk about? If not then that could be a reason for calling back on xy...

Comment: Boys do love talking about their chromosomes...

Answer (score 8):

> How can i say this politely?

"*We have been talking a lot about INSERT TOPIC HERE, can we talk about something else please?*"

After that is said, bring up a topic that will be **mutually interesting to you both**, and start a new conversation.

If they refuse to stop talking about *INSERT TOPIC HERE*, find someone else to eat lunch with.

Comment: Without knowing what 'xy' is related to, this still might come across as rude, what if it's about his colleagues newly born child. Parents can be very touchy when told they talk to much about their kids etc. I like this approach but I think without more context it's still a risky response to the topic 'xy'.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt check out the link in my comment above.  It tells you what xy is.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt In that case they go with option number 2, eat lunch with someone else.

Comment: @Snow how sure are you that OP is referring to the "XY problem" and not just to some topic he's dubbed 'xy'. Why would the "XY problem" be a "pleasant subject to him and matters a lot to him", that seems an odd statement to associate with it wouldn't you agree. Or are you telling me I should apply the "XY problem" to my critique of this answer?

Comment: @IamSoNotListening I guess that depends on how valuable the working relationship is, +1 for the second part I guess.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt I assumed that from the makeup of the question and the fact that the OP is active on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Snow I’m pretty sure it’s a placeholder- the question doesn’t really make much sense if he’s talking about the XY problem...

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt its pretty close to that.

Answer (score 1):

Just tell him straight (and mess with his head a little at the same time).

> Yeah, I know you're really into XY, but I'm concerned that you're getting fixated by this more than the problem it's trying to solve.

While he's trying to untangle this train of thought, surprise him by changing the subject.

Comment: And if he discusses this with someone else and they don't feel he is "fixated" on this subject, then you become the problem. If you want to tell it to him straight, just say you prefer to talk about something else.

Answer (score 1):

First of all let him talk a little about his favor subject, as long it is not offensive to you. He would appreciate it and this will strengthen the friendship. Then, after a few minutes change into a subject that is mutually interesting by saying something like "Meanwhile, what to you thing about ZZ ..."